# error :Unable to acquire a lockedBuffer, very likely client tries to lock more than maxImages buffers

Tags: android, image-processing, camera, android-camera

I am using camera2 api for capturing image and displaying in thumnail .Everything is working fine in all devices but when using `Micromax Q382` device then in thumnail preview its displaying black image.I am getting below Issue

```
Unable to acquire a lockedBuffer, very likely client tries to lock more than maxImages buffers
```

i am using below code for capture listerner callback

```
final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback()
        {

            @Override
            public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request,
                                           TotalCaptureResult result)
            {

                super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);

                startPreview();
            }

        };

        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback()
        {

            @Override
            public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session)
            {

                try {
                    session.capture(captureBuilder.build(), captureListener, backgroudHandler);
                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    AppLogger.exception(myContext, getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
                    // e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session)
            {

            }
        }, backgroudHandler);

    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        AppLogger.exception(myContext, getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
        // e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and below code using for OnImageAvailableListener

```
ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader)
            {

                Image image = null;
                try {
                    image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                    // ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                    // final byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];

                    ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                    final byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];

                    buffer.get(bytes);
                    save(bytes);
                    buffer.clear();
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            mThumbnail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            filePathLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            filePathValue.setText(file.getAbsolutePath());

                            Bitmap bmp =
                                    UtilityMethods.getScaledBitmap(CameraImageTestActivityLoliipop.this, bytes);
                            mThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                        }
                    });

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    AppLogger.exception(myContext, getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
                    // e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    AppLogger.exception(myContext, getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
                    // e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (image != null) {
                        image.close();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please provide log output from before the error as well, and the whole exception stack trace, to see where the error is being generated and in what circumstances.

Comment: Its not throwing any exception,but i found something that when i am capturing picture then at last movement camera preview for a second gets black it means the photo which i am capturing is black. I think this should be the issue. But i have tried to change property but did't get any solution yet...

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: what `ImageFormat` have you set when initialising the `ImageReader`?

Comment: @tropicalfish **ImageFormat.JPEG**

Answer (score 18):

You may provide parameter `maxImages` as `1` for method `ImageReader.newInstance`. `acquireLatestImage` calls `acquireNextSurfaceImage` before close the only one image buffer, which lead to this warning.

Use `acquireNextImage` in this case. If `maxImages` is bigger than `1`, `acquireLatestImage` don't have this problem.

Comment: I am a noob for this. May you please elaborate, where and how to make changes. It's urgent requirement for me. Please Consider.

Comment: @KartikArora use `Image.acquireNextImage()` instead of `Image.acquireLatestImage()` when your ImageReader's `maxImages` variable is set to 1.

Answer (score 6):

After setting maxImages to 2 and using acquireLatestImage, if you are still getting into issue where you stopped getting onImageAvailable callback then  most likely you are not releasing the Image buffer you got from acquireLatestImage(), buffer will not be available unless you call Image.close() on that image and allow the same buffer for reuse.

```
    Image raw = imageReader.acquireLatestImage();
    raw.close();
```

Here is the link for documentation:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Image.html#close()

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of `ImageReader.acquireLatestImage()`:

> Acquire the latest Image from the ImageReader's queue, dropping older
>   images. Returns null if no new image is available. This operation will
>   acquire all the images possible from the ImageReader, but close() all
>   images that aren't the latest.
>
> **This function is recommended to use
>   over acquireNextImage() for most use-cases**, as it's more suited for
>   real-time processing. Note that **maxImages should be at least 2 for
>   acquireLatestImage()** to be any different than acquireNextImage() -
>   discarding all-but-the-newest Image requires temporarily acquiring two
>   Images at once.

Thus, for real-time processing use:

- `ImageReader.newInstance(..., maxImages = 2)` with
- `imageReader.acquireLatestImage()`

Of if your use-case is different (e.g. batch/background processing), use e.g.:

- `ImageReader.newInstance(..., maxImages = 1)` with
- `imageReader.acquireNextImage()`
- Be aware, that (from documentation of `acquireNextImage()`:

> This operation will fail by throwing an IllegalStateException if
>   maxImages have been acquired with acquireNextImage() or
>   acquireLatestImage(). In particular a sequence of acquireNextImage()
>   or acquireLatestImage() calls greater than maxImages without calling
>   close() in-between will exhaust the underlying queue. At such a time,
>   IllegalStateException will be thrown until more images are released
>   with close().